# Accessing a certain I/O controller using memory-mapped I/O

Tags: c, io, constants

I have a program that accesses a certain I/O controller using memory-mapped I/O. I currently store the base address of this controller in a `const` variable.

This leads to a code structure something like this:

**gpio.h:**

```
int gpioFunc (unsigned int pin, unsigned int func);

int setGpio (unsigned int pin, unsigned int val);
```

**gpio.c:**

```
#include "gpio.h"
unsigned volatile int* const gpioAddr = (unsigned int*) 0x20200000;

int gpioFunc (unsigned int pin, unsigned int func)
{
    //code that uses the variable
}

int setGpio (unsigned int pin, unsigned int val)
{
    //code that uses the variable
}
```

**main.c:**

```
#include "gpio.h"
void main ()
{
    gpioFunc (16,1);
    setGpio(16,0);
    hlt();
}
```

I have always been uncertain of the best practices in C as to where to put constants.  Does this way make sense, or would it be better practice to put it somewhere else?  If so, where?

Answer (score 2):

You should make a small driver layer, so that the main doesn't know about the low level details of what is going on - and here in that .c file that you have implemented the driver in, the constants goes as well.

Then you call your driver and all is good :)

Comment: I think this may what I have currently... how would this be different from my current implementation? Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, this is not a driver. This is calling the bare metal layer from your main. You want to make a small driver layer, so that you get calls like "<driver_name>_get<data_pin_name>" and "<driver_name>_init". This also allows you to easily change the setup in the future, when you need to.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to declare `gpioAddr` variable as static. That way the program can only access it from `gpio.c` and nowhere else (unless you somehow pass the address of the variable to somewhere, which is a poor design, IMO). Making it static also helps the compiler to optimize the variable and just generates code for reading from/writing to the particular memory address.

Also, `0x20200000` is a magic number, you should consider to define it somewhere appropriate.

Lastly, casting as `(unsigned volatile int*)` may be better for readability, although it makes no difference.

**Edit:** The appropriate place for defining constants depend on the context. If these definitions are needed somewhere else, you *must* put them in header file. Defining them in source file is more appropriate otherwise, as unnecessary information would be hidden. Unfortunately, `#define` preprocessor directives in C are in the global namespace, so appropriate prefixes should be added to the name regardless of the definition place.

Comment: I am aware that I should consider to define it somewhere appropriate. The question was where would be considered appropriate?

Comment: It is the source file if it does not needed to know from somewhere else, i.e. including a header file, header file if otherwise. I think source file is more appropriate in this occasion.